# Assertions On setTimeout When Using react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a notification that appears and then disappears after 4 seconds. I'm using setTimeout to achieve this behavior. In my tests I'm trying to use `jest.useFakeTimers` and then expect the call to `setTimeout`. But I'm getting a lot of extra calls to `setTimeout` that I'm not expecting. I was finally able to track down that the calls are coming from the `@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim` package which looks like it's used in `dom-testing-library`.

Is there a way to assert on the number of calls to `setTimeout` if I'm using react-testing-library?